# Configurable Cron job in Lambda

Tags: cron, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying to figure out how I can set up a conditional cron job in Lambda for my below Scenario:

I have an SQS queue and I have to create a Lambda function which publish a message to SNS only in between 7 AM to 5 PM if we have a delayed message attribute set in the SQS. So basically this Lambda will act as a subscriber for SQS and publisher for SNS.

So just wondering how we can make the cron job conditional based upon the SQS message attributes?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the Lambda function to trigger off a CloudWatch Logs cron event, then poll through SQS messages in the Lambda function to search for the delayed message attribute.

To set up the cron trigger:

- Navigate to CloudWatch in the console
- Events > Rules > Create Rule
- Select Schedule > Cron expression > `cron(0/10 2-7 * * ? *)`
- For Target, select your Lambda function.

This will trigger your Lambda function to run every 10 minutes between 02:00-07:00 UTC every day. Inside the Lambda function if will be up to you to pull messages from the queue and delete from the queue when consumed by the Lambda function.